# Enable PPPoE before login

Tags: macos

I have a Mac and need to remote control it for some work.

Normally it works well, but I have problem to reconnect it when it rebooted. It seems like the problem is that Mac will not connect to internet via PPPoE before I login in, so it doesn't work if I put any PPPoE shortcut into my login startup item.

Is there any way to connect PPPoE without login? (if possible, login without password would be be last option)

Answer (score 0):

If your PPPoE connection is set to "connect when needed" then put a webloc file into your Login Items list and it will trigger the system to connect to the net.